# Dúvida com relacionamento de tabelas Banco de Dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Boa tarde, estou desenvolvendo um sistema para meu aprendizado e me deparei com uma situação onde fiquei na dúvida.

Tenho a tabela no banco em que são gravadas as perguntas.

**Tabela pergunta :**
-IdPergunta;
-IdUsuários;

Tanto o que perguntou, quanto os que responderam gravam nessa tabela.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, devo criar uma tabela resposta para gravar as respostas ou gravo na tabela Pergunta mesmo ?

Comment: Não sei. Depende do que precisa fazer com essas informações, depende de outros pontos do banco de dados, depende do conceito exato que isso significa. Tem que avaliar as vantagens e desvantagens de fazer de um jeito ou de outro.

Comment: uma dúvida que surgiu enquanto desenvolvo a nível de aprendizado ...

Comment: As perguntas podem ser respondidas mais de uma vez? Se sim, já é um forte indicativo que terá que criar uma nova tabela - se for trabalhar com normalização, é claro. Assim como o bigown disse, você precisa fazer os levantamentos necessários. Dos dois jeitos estará "certo".

Answer (score 2):

A resposta é: depende.

Uma dica muito boa quando se vai fazer o desenho de uma tabela no banco de dados é perguntar quais são suas entidades de trabalho e quais relacionamentos essas entidades tem entre si. Esse modelo de abstração é o [`modelo entidade relacionamento`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo_entidade_relacionamento), `MER`.

Ao pensar em um relacionamento, pense também qual a *aridade* desse relacionamento. Por exemplo, se um usuário pode realizar múltiplas perguntas e pode escrever múltiplas  resposta, cada pergunta podendo ter várias respostas, temos o seguinte modelo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que não coloquei os atributos no modelo, isso é um outro passo.

As chaves primárias, muitas vezes, podem ser chaves artificiais; nos demais casos, podemos criar as chaves artificiais para fazer a ligação, respeitando apenas a unicidade. [Esse artigo](http://www.slipmp.com/blog/tipos-de-chaves-em-um-banco-de-dados/) explica aqui um pouco do que é a chave artificial.

Após saber quais são suas entidades e como elas se relacionam, transformaamos o `MER` em um modelo mais próximo do banco de dados relacional, o [`Modelo Relacional`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo_relacional), `MR`. O modelo relacional é um jeito de se escrever estruturas de tabelas graficamente. No `phpmyadmin` é possível você criar tabelas usando esse modelo através de uma interface bem divertida de se mexer. Achei [essa resposta no SO internacional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166687/how-do-i-enable-phpmyadmins-designer-view) sobre como habilitar essa funcionalidade no `phpmyadmin`.

O `MR` é composta de tabelas e ligações/chaves estrangeiras primariamente. Uma tabela é uma coleção de dados bem conhecida, uma [`tupla`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enupla) cujas posições são nomeadas. Por exemplo, quando se diz que um usuário precisa ter um nome e uma pontuação, ele pode ser representado pela `tupla` `('Fernando', 64)`, sendo a primeira posição da `tupla` o nome do usuário e a segunda posição a pontuação do mesmo usuário; cada coluna da tabela é representada por uma posição na `tupla`.

Eu gosto de usar a seguinte técnica para converter de `MER` para `MR`:

```
1-> se o relacionamento de A--B é de 1 para 1, então coloca os atributos de B em A
2-> se o relacionamento de A--B é de 1 para 0..1, então coloca os atributos de B em A apenas caso exista dados pertinentes, sendo todos nulos caso não exista B
3-> se o relacionamento de A--B é de 1 para 0..n, então coloca em B uma chave estrangeira para A
4-> se o relacionamento de A--B é de 0..n para 0..n, então crio uma tabela de ligação que contém chave estrangeira para A e chave estrangeira para B
5-> toda tabela advinda de uma entidade tem uma chave artificial
6-> todo atributo da entidade vira uma coluna na tabela
```

Assim, o `MER` postado acima se transforma no seguinte `MR` (assumindo que resposta tem texto, pergunta tem texto e usuário tem nome e pontos):

```
PERGUNTA(pk_pergunta, fk_usuario, texto_pergunta)
RESPOSTA(pk_resposta, fk_usuario, fk_pergunta, texto_resposta)
USUARIO(pk_usuario, nome, pontos)
```

Claro, você poderia modelar de outra maneira as entidades. Você poderia dizer que existem `posts`, sendo que um `post` pode ser de abertura *ou* ser um `post` de resposta, desde que o `post` de resposta se referencie a um outro `post`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Que se transforma no seguinte `MR`:

```
POST(pk_post, fk_usuario, fk_post_original, texto_post)
USUARIO(pk_usuario, nome, pontos)
```