# SQL - Unir tabela de pedidos e produtos

Tags: mysql

Estou com a seguinte tabela de **PEDIDOS**:

```
 `PEDIDOS`(`PEDID`, `PEDIDUSUARIO`, `PEDSTATUS`, `PEDVAL`, `PEDFORMAPAG`, `PEDTROCO`, `PEDDATA`)
```

E a seguinte tabela de produtos, onde cada linha inserida contém o id do pedido ao qual esse produto pertence:

```
 `PRODUTOS`(`PRODID`, `PRODPEDID`, `PRODNOME`, `PRODQUANT`, `PRODVAL`)
```

Logo, para cada registro em *PEDIDO* existe um ou muitos registros em *PRODUTOS*
(pedido = carrinho de compras, produtos = produtos no carrinho).

Estou listando todos os pedidos com sucesso, mas de que forma eu poderia  consultar na mesma query os produtos?

Uso PHP e retorno os dados em JSON, meu único problema é o SQL mesmo.

Comment: Você precisa de uma tabela de relação intermediária `ITENS`, que contém o referência para o produto e para o pedido em questão. Essa é uma tabela de relacionamento, mas nada impede que ela tenha atributos próprios, como o item do produto 2 ser vendido a R$50 a unidade, sendo vendidas 2 unidades

Comment: Para isso eu precisaria predefinir um número máximo de produtos no carrinho, que seria a quantidade de colunas da nova tabela ITENS? Assim registraria o id de cada produto

Comment: Eu trabalho com um sistema de força de vendas, e devo falar que não é necessário fazer nenhuma limitação na quantidade de colunas. Creio que você não entendeu como funciona uma tabela de relacionamento; estou a digitar uma resposta mais completa sobre o assunto

Comment: Até entendi, mas não consegui visualizar. Obrigado

Comment: Espero que minha resposta tenha removido suas dúvidas

Comment: Sim, tirou, estou fazendo os testes

Comment: Atualizei a minha resposta colocando um link que trabalha com o algoritmo de conversão de MER para MR

Comment: Valeu, funcionou aqui!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você encontra-se numa típica relação `n,m`.

No caso, seu problema de produtos inclusos em vendas é o mesmo problema de alunos matriculados em disciplinas:

[image: relacionamentos many-to-many, fonte original http://www.shsu.edu/~csc_tjm/summer2000/cs334/Chapter04/part1/Chapt16087.jpg]

No caso, o esquema acima está no Modelo Entidade-Relacionamento, ou MER. Esse modelo é muito útil para fazer a modelagem rápida dos dados, e também para ter um entendimento profundo do negócio envolvido. Porém, nem tudo são flores. SQL não é compatível diretamente com MER, pois SQL segue o Modelo Relacional, MR, baseado na álgebra relacional.

Para transformar de MER para MR, é muito importante saber a aridade do relacionamento. No seu caso, a parte interessante é no relacionamento *muitos-para-muitos*, em inglês *many-to-many*.

> Mais sobre transformar MER em MR [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195573/64969)

Em um relacionamento *many-to-many*, você tem `m` entidades de um tipo se relacionando com `n` entidades do outro tipo. Nesse caso, você cria uma tabela intermediária com chaves estrangeiras para as duas tabelas de entidade. Exemplo:

> Eu vendi uma furadeira e dois serrotes.
>
> Minha tabela da entidade `produto`:
>
> ```
> produto
> | prodid | prodnome  |
> +--------+-----------+
> | 1      | serrote   |
> | 2      | furadeira |
> ```
>
> Minha tabela da entidade `pedido`:
>
> ```
> pedido
> | pedid |
> +-------+
> | 1984  |
> ```
>
> Minha tabela para o relacionamento:
>
> ```
> item
> | itemid   | prodid | pedid | quant | valor  |
> +----------+--------+-------+-------+--------+
> | 1783     | 1      | 1984  | 2.0   | 10.00  |
> | 2123     | 2      | 1984  | 1.0   | 150.00 |
> ```

Para saber quais são os produtos (e suas quantidades) no pedido 1984:

```
SELECT
    prod.prodnome,
    i.quant
FROM
    pedido ped
        inner join item i on (ped.pedid = i.pedid)
        inner join produto prod on (i.prodid = prod.prodid)
WHERE
    ped.pedid = 1984
```

No meu caso, estou modelando de acordo com necessidades que já passei na empresa onde trabalho. Há casos em que se deseja vender o mesmo item duas ou mais vezes no mesmo pedido (por exemplo, como item de bonificação, troca e venda propriamente dita), então eu defino sua chave primária como `itemid`. Na maioria dos casos, entretanto, uma relação `n,m` normalmente não tem a repetição das entidades.

Answer (score 0):

2 opçoes:

- INNER JOIN
- LEFT OUTER JOIN

**Com INNER JOIN**

```
SELECT campo_tabela1,campo_tabela2
FROM TABELA_1
INNER JOIN TABELA_2
ON idx_tabela2 = idx_tabela1
```

Neste caso vc vai ter resultados SO no caso onde o INNER JOIN esta OK. Ao seja, se tem na TABELA_1, um registro que não tem idx_tabela2 = idx_tabela1, ele não vai aparecer.
Então  caso de uma tabela de clientes + uma tabela de produto vc vai ter só os clientes que tem produto. Os clientes que não tem produtos não vão aparecer.

**Com LEFT OUTER JOIN**

```
SELECT campo_tabela1,campo_tabela2
FROM TABELA_1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABELA_2
ON idx_tabela2 = idx_tabela1
```

Neste caso, no resultado vc vai ter os dados da TABELA_1 que tem idx_tabela2 = idx_tabela1 mais vai ter também os outros.
Ou seja, vc vai ter os clientes que tem produtos + os clientes que não tem.
No caso de clientes que não tem produtos, a valor dos campos da tabela dos produtos vai ser "null" o que é um valor bem especifica no SQL.